# Java 2 Objective-C NSArray

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c

I'm using java 2 objective-c convector in order to create iOS app. This convector: http://code.google.com/p/j2objc/

This is my first time of using the objective-c. So I can't solve the problem below:

Originally I have got this line.

```
static final short[] ar = new short[]{(short)0, (short)0, (short)1,(short)0};
```

After Java2ObjC I got this. The compilator gives me an error here (short, int, double can't convert to id):

```
 NSArray * const ar = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(short)0, (short)0, (short)1, (short)0]
```

The same problem for double values.

What is the right way to inicialize final static constant array with values?

**I've been used used convertor in windows. Now I see that was wrong. Use j2ObjC only in MacOs**

Comment: Why won't you go learn Objective-c? It's way better than some converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems is that an `NSArray` can only hold `NSObject` or derived classes:

```
 NSArray * const ar = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithShort:0], [NSNumber numberWithShort:0], [NSNumber numberWithShort:1], [NSNumber numberWithShort:0], nil];
```

or with the new shorthand notation:

```
 NSArray * const ar = @[[NSNumber numberWithShort:0], [NSNumber numberWithShort:0], [NSNumber numberWithShort:1], [NSNumber numberWithShort:0]];
```

Or use a plain C array:

```
short const ar[4] = {0,0,1,0};
```

Comment: I think this is the most useful answer. Thanks. Is it possible to use just plain C-code in Objective-C with no additional plug-ins?

Comment: Objective-C is just C with some extra classes, you can mis C and Objective-C a much as you want.

Comment: +1 For the `NSArray arrayWithObjects` shorthand notation, didn't know about that until now :)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using j2objc, you are using https://code.google.com/p/java2objc/. Completely separate projects, unfortunately with similar names.

Please update your question to refer to the correct project.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the short example to add multiple objects in objective-c

```
    NSArray *consArr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithShort:0], 
   [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize array with the method "arrayWithObjects". You should only add objects, like this

```
NSNumber * number1 = [NSNumber alloc] initWithShort:0];
NSNumber * number2 = [NSNumber alloc] initWithShort:0];
```

Then,

```
NSArray * const ar = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:number1,number2, nil];
```

should work